# can't update form from gridview1_RowCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview and a label in an updatepanel. I want to change the label in rowcommand handler but I can't. the event is firing but there is no changes in the form. I checked that viewstate is on and also tried to call updatepanel.update() from rowcommand handler but with no success. What can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be solved if you will use standard command names such as SORT for controls that invoke row command, then it is works as needed updating the grid and the form